# Kendo UI Window does not respond to data-bind visible settings

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm trying to toggle the visible property of a `Kendo UI` window through the data-bind method using an MVVM pattern but it is not responding as it should according to the Kendo documentation.

```
<div id="KendoWindow"
    data-role="window"  
    data-bind="visible:WindowVisible"
    data-title="Title does not show"
    data-width="500"
    data-height="300"
>
    <div class="span4"  > 
            <label for="Comment">Comments</label>   
            <textarea id ="Comment"  data-bind="value: Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
```

I am initializing it properly but if I set the WinowVisible property to false in the viewModel like so,

```
this.set("WindowVisible", false);
```

the window stays visible.

If I set it through jQuery like so :

```
 var dialog = $("#KendoWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.setOptions({
           visible:false
        });
```

it will then become invisible. Then I can't make it visible again if I run this code:

```
var dialog = $("#KendoWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.setOptions({
           visible:true
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding data-visible="false" to the window, then when the ShowWindow becomes true, it should become visible.  I have a checkbox bound to the boolean value, as well as a button click function setting the boolean and both seem to work fine.

See sample...

http://jsbin.com/jecih/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I think my biggest issue was trying to combine non MVVM methods with MVVM methods and the two were clashing with each other. I have implemented your solution and it works great! Reduced my  many lines of code to just a couple.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work, though? I have a similar problem but am not in a position to bind another control to the showWindow property. All I can do, is get the model and set the property to true... this shows and everything works. But once the window is closed, once, it will never show again - despite using the same code that sets 'showWindow' to true, that worked the first time. Seems like it really should be a bug

Comment: Great answer! However I noticed by me and in your example as well that once you close the window with the close action in the window and then reopen the window it will open very small and not close with the close action in the window.